# xcode archive nib error

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, nib

```
/Users/userName/Desktop/AppName/trunk/CreditBank/Sections/.../BalanceCell.xib: error: Compilation failed. Unable to write to path: /Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CreditBank-cgzxewosyynfhugrlyacqrguemkn/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/CreditBank.app/BalanceCell~iphone.nib
  Underlying Errors:
        Description: The file “objects-8.0+.nib” doesn’t exist.
        Failure Reason: The file doesn’t exist.
        Underlying Errors:
            Description: The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory
            Failure Reason: No such file or directory
```

I can run on a device but it's almost impossible to archive. As well it occurs during Archive operations, and often it prevents me from completing the archive step.

Comment: I suggest you make the formatting of your question a bit nicer. StackOverflow has [a bunch of options for formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). This will **help people to help you**.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is it just this file, and can you delete it and start over?

Comment: try to clean the project and build again